# username, password etc hardcoded into program - how to pick them up from a file instead?

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jdbc, configuration-files

I have made some code in ECLIPSE. As you can see, the username, password, database URL, SQL Queries are hardcoded into my program. I don't want to change my code and recompile it every time I change the password, username of my database or modify the query. For that reason, I want to put these "parameters" inside a file (text, XML, json ???). I want to be able to change the parameters easily.
So what should I do ? What kind of file should I use ? I want to avoid XML, json because 
you need to know both well. XML and JSON can be difficult when the code grows big.

```
import java.sql.*;

public class JDBCDemo {


static String query = 
        "SELECT customerno, name " +
        "FROM customers;";


public static void main(String[]args)
{
    String username = "cowboy";
    String password = "123456";
    try
    {
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/business", username, password);
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    }catch(SQLException ex){System.out.println("Exception! " + ex);}

}

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use 
[Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) 
and read the values from a .properties file.

Comment: Unless you package your application as a jar, then you will need to rebuild every time you change the properties file.

Comment: @klong :  Not really.  you can use the command line to add a directory to your classpath where the properties file will live:  java -cp config/ JDBCDemo

Comment: @Matt - I don't use the command line much. How do i do this in eclipse ? If I add a directory, my code will become OS dependent. How do I prevent that ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this](http://www.bartbusschots.ie/blog/?p=360) helps. It's an example of such config files.

Answer (score 0):

```
InputStream inputStream = null;
Properties properties = new Properties();
try {
    inputStream = JDBCDemo.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("jdbc.properties");
    properties.load(inputStream);
}
finally {
    try { 
        if (inputStream != null) {
             inputStream.close();
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        ;//ignore
    }
}

String username = properties.get("username");
```

Answer (score 0):

XML and JSON are structured formats so they needs to be [parsed](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/javax.xml.parsers/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java.html).

Text file will be the simplest to implement but because it is unstructured the end user is going to need going to need to know the internal format understood by your program. For instance an extra space may break your program.

Answer (score 0):

Ever think of using spring injection where u can create one config file containing all hardcoded variables which through getters and setters can be put into your code. Then in the future if any of these variables need changing you only change 1 file
http://www.springsource.org/javaconfig/

Answer (score 0):

generally the uer-id & passwords (rather any resource that needs to be configured from outside your JAR/WAR) is stored in a Properties file as a key value pair. You can then access them using ResourceBundle class : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html

Answer (score 0):

For `sql` queries you could use a database `function` or `procedure` which returns some kind of cursor similar to `SYS_REFCURSOR` in `Oracle` and call the `function` or `procedure` from front end. By doing this you could avoid hard coding of sql queries in java code.

Regards